# Pairing angular js directives with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

What's the best way to manipulate a template of a ng directive with jQuery? When I try to animate or toggle classes that are inside a directive's template, nothing happens. For instance:

HTML:

```
<div class="projects"> 
    <h2>Projects</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row" ng-controller="ProjectsController">
                <div class="project-boxes" ng-repeat="project in projects">
                    <projects-info info="project"></projects-info>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive's template:

```
<div class="prjcontainer">
    <img class="boximg" ng-src="{{ info.img }}">
    <p> {{ info.description }}</p>
</div>
```

Script

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('.boximg').hover(
function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 
        width: '300px', 
        height: '300px'}, 500);
}, 
function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 
        width: '100px', 
        height: '100px' }, 500);
});
```

Directive code:

```
app.directive('projectsInfo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'components/projects/projects-template/projectsInfo.html'
  };
});
```

My main goal is to have a info viewer like how on the Netflix site when you hover over a show, the picture gets bigger and text displays on the inside.

Thanks!

Comment: You should do it in directive ddo link function.

Comment: @Jai What's the advantages of that?

Comment: @Jai I looked at the documentation but I'm not 100% clear on how it works or how it differs

Comment: Show directive code...   would be `element.hover(...` in directive.

Comment: @Jai what is `ddo`?  I've never seen that abbreviation myself

Comment: @charlietfl it is directive definition object.https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile&ei=FSbAUmdi&lc=en-IN&geid=10&s=1&m=436&ts=1454077716&sig=ALL1Aj59ZQg1_oGfaJo0GxMACm4j0TCi7g

Comment: @charlietfl What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the element is exposed in the directive as a jQuery object ... show us the directive code

Comment: @charlietfl okay I added it